# Adding two form variables with calculating and comparing

Tags: javascript

I have items "item1 costs $1" and "item2 costs $2"

I made a simple form to calculate the total price of both BUT if the customer will purchase more than **50 items** (total items = item1 + item2) I will give him a 50% discount which means the final price will be divided by 2 BUT only if we the total is more than "50".

What I am getting that the price is getting divided by 2 even if the total is only = 10 !!

Here's the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2yTLp/225/

```js
var x = document.getElementById("x");
var y = document.getElementById("y");
var d = document.getElementById("d");
var xstored = x.getAttribute("data-in");
var ystored = y.getAttribute("data-in");
setInterval(function(){
    if( x == document.activeElement ){
     var temp = x.value;
     if( xstored != temp ){
       xstored = temp;
       x.setAttribute("data-in",temp);
       calculate();
     }
    }

    if( y == document.activeElement ){
     var temp = y.value;
     if( ystored != temp ){
       ystored = temp;
       y.setAttribute("data-in",temp);
       calculate();
     }
    }
},50);
function calculate(){
var total =  x.value + y.value;
if( total >= 50 ){
d.innerHTML = ((x.value * 1.00) + (y.value * 2.00)) / 2;
}

else{
d.innerHTML = (x.value * 1.00) + (y.value * 2.00);
}

}
x.onblur = calculate;
calculate();
```

```css
#d{
    text-indent:20px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Calculate</h3>
item1&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="x" data-in="" type="number" /><br>
<br>
item2&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="y" data-in="" type="number" /><br>
<br>
Please Pay and amount of <span id="d"></span>
```

it's very easy but can't figure it out.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are concatenating strings instead of sum numbers. Please, convert the values to numbers and it works perfectly. See the line commented:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("x");
var y = document.getElementById("y");
var d = document.getElementById("d");
var xstored = x.getAttribute("data-in");
var ystored = y.getAttribute("data-in");
setInterval(function(){
  if( x == document.activeElement ){
    var temp = x.value;
    if( xstored != temp ){
      xstored = temp;
      x.setAttribute("data-in",temp);
      calculate();
    }
  }

  if( y == document.activeElement ){
    var temp = y.value;
    if( ystored != temp ){
      ystored = temp;
      y.setAttribute("data-in",temp);
      calculate();
    }
  }
},50);
function calculate(){
  //here you need to convert values to numbers
  var total =  Number(x.value) + Number(y.value);
  if( total >= 50 ){
    d.innerHTML = ((x.value * 1.00) + (y.value * 2.00)) / 2;
  }

  else{
    d.innerHTML = (x.value * 1.00) + (y.value * 2.00);
  }

}
x.onblur = calculate;
calculate();
```

```css
#d{
    text-indent:20px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Calculate</h3>
item1&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="x" data-in="" type="number" /><br>
<br>
item2&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="y" data-in="" type="number" /><br>
<br>
Please Pay and amount of <span id="d"></span>
```

The explanation is if you concatenate this:

```
 var one = "10";
 var two = "15";
 var result = one + two ; // result string "1015"
```

But if you change to numbers the sum is perfect

```
 var one = "10";
 var two = "15";
 var result = Number(one) + Number(two) ; // result int 25
```

Comment: You're welcome :) Accept the answer when you can do it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It is very straight and simple
Your code is correct except one thing, you didn't use **parseInt**,
currently you are **concatenating** the values instead of **adding**,

so just replace this code

```
var total =  x.value + y.value;
```

with this one

```
var total =  parseInt(x.value) + parseInt(y.value);
```

That's it :)